# genymotion freezes entire Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: android, ubuntu, freeze, genymotion, ubuntu-16.04

I recently downloaded the latest Genymotion version,2.7.2 (I had a previous version before, I don't remember which exactly) however whenever I try to launch an emulator, the device pops up for about a minute but before loading completely it freezes. Not only that, but when this happens the entire Desktop freezes. I'm able to move the cursor, but nothing else responds (even the clock stops working). No clicks or keys do anything and I'm forced to restart my Desktop via the power button on my machine. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

I've tried 3 separate times with 3 separate emulated devices and the same thing happens every time. Until I get this fixed I can't do my job, so I would really like some advice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Had same problem,
I changed video card driver from Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers
rebooted and no freeze again

Comment: On my Ubuntu I get this : Unknown : Unknown This device uses a alternative driver. Radiobutton 1 below this(selected) : Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs by intel-microcode are used. Radiobutton 2(unselected) : Dont use this device. Below this there is the message : 1 propiertary driver is used. What can I do ? Thanks for advice.

Comment: You changed video card driver from what to what? What a vague answer.

Comment: I changed my graphics driver from "xserver-nouveau" to "nvidia 440" and it solved my issue

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution worked for me. I changed the generic to the Nvidia 445 driver. Also, I deactivated "Secure Boot" because it was a problem for me to change my driver due to that.

Comment: you have to restart after you change driver.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error on 16.04, fixed it by uninstalling virtualbox, then reinstalling from the deb image from the official page here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

then running

sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms

also switched to nvidia proprietary drivers

Answer (score 0):

Some of these VMs from Genymotion are using more memory than you know. When creating a Virtual Device in Genymotion, I used the down-arrow to ensure I had enough system memory to run. Look at the attached screenshots.

I have a 6GB system and I didn't realize a Samsung Galaxy S8 was using 4GB RAM. Switching to the Google Nexus 9, which is running 2GB RAM, I was able to launch without the sluggishness.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLcxQ.png)Genymotion seems to run with VirtualBox. Therefore, launching VirtualBox will show you the created VMs from Geny. From there, you can use the Settings in VirtualBox to change the RAM size.

I hope this helps someone because it drove me crazy.

[Genymotion showing how much RAM is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LCoX.png)

Comment: This is good advice for proactively determining whether you have the resources to run a given VM, but what should the author do if they have verified that they have enough memory to run the VM and are still experiencing this kind of freezing?